# Socket.io - nothing gets written to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've been trying to start with Socket.io and the initial example on their site doesn't work for me. This is what I'm trying to do:
my Server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

my index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log('inside');
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
  console.log(socket);
</script>
```

There are couple of questions on stackoverflow, but nothing that I can co-relate,I'm not getting a 404 error.

My project structure is like this:

ProjectName:

- Node Modules
- Server.js
- index.html

I really don't know what's happening, Please help.Thanks.

Comment: wondering - is your socket.io js file even loaded on the client end (check in the browser if the javascript was loaded or not).  Have you tried using a different listening port for socket.io on the server(and hence changing the port on the client end as well)

Comment: I tried both Ali, I used a different port, and also I've seen that socket.js was loaded on the client side.

Comment: try the bare socket.io http server by doing `require("socket.io").listen(PORT)` try to use a higher port number like `9999` , on client side try `io.connect('http://localhost:PORT')` it should be working since its one of the simplest examples, if problem persists, try looking any firewalls or anti-virus or sys configuration that might block it

Comment: Thanks Geo, It started working - After changing the port!